# Is there Applescript code to get mac contacts profile picture?

Tags: image, macos, profile, contacts

Please suggest,

I need Applescript code to get profile picture url or path or location of mac's default app for address book "contacts" profile picture.

Thank in advance,
Bharath

Comment: Contacts is a sandboxed app, but it appears to store the images in "~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Images", via an alias to the images folder. However they're labelled by a GUID, so linking the GUID to the right image is going to be problematic.

Comment: In OSX 10.9.5 there is no folder such as ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Images